# .htaccess for moved forum and seo url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a problem with my `.htaccess` file.
I recently moved the forum (IPB) that was in the root path in a subdirectory, so I wrote this `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ forum/index.php
```

And this worked very well.
Basically, I wanted that old urls that were pointing to forum, were redirected to **forum** subdir.

But here's the problem.
In the root path now, there is a index.php that will be the new website, I want SEO friendly urls, so I wrote this line

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this rule doesn't work.
Every request like

```
www.domain.com/view/welcome/
```

redirect to a 404 page of the IPB forum.

I tried also to put some RewriteCond but the result is the same,
every url involving the new index.php in the root path turns in a 404 Page.

EDIT:
In /forum/
There is this `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.shtml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /public/404.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Rule below you match only digits after view but want `welcome`

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

change to

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

and add some lines to void unnecessary redirects

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ forum/index.php
```

Comment: Still not working. I believe the problem is the rule I used to redirect the request to /forum/, But I can't find  the solution

Comment: try now. i've  extended the answer

Comment: Sorry, I  took your line, when was extending the answer :( What is just now?

Comment: I noticed, and wrote the correct line, but It doesn't work. I can't really uderstand :( , There is the way to redirect only urls that after domain.com has specific keywords?

Comment: I found the problem. I test without domain control. But in those lines mistake was. I've rewrited

Comment: still doesn't work. In the subfolder forum there is a .htaccess, Edited the first post. Can be this the cause?

Comment: we make by the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1` url like /forum/welkome. Than forum's htaccess loose welkome.  Maybe you need make it as /forum/index.php?welkome or /forum/index.php?url = welkome ? what is url format of blog ?

Comment: I think that the issue is another. I've used some PHP code to include some function of IPB, I think that the cause is this. The function of ipsRegistry handle the url request and avoid htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!
I was using this:

```
/* Configuration: Path to IP.Board */
define( 'IPB_LOC', 'forum/' );
define( 'IPS_ENFORCE_ACCESS', TRUE );//DAMN COSTANT

/* Load IP.Board files */
require_once( IPB_LOC . 'conf_global.php' );
require_once( IPB_LOC . 'initdata.php' );
require_once( IPB_LOC . CP_DIRECTORY. '/sources/base/ipsRegistry.php' );

/* Init Registry */
ipsRegistry::init();

/* Fetch Member */
$member = ipsRegistry::member()->fetchMemberData(); 
$loggedIn = (bool) $member['member_id'];
```

To check if the user was logged in the forum, but I haven't wrote this line

```
define( 'IPS_ENFORCE_ACCESS', TRUE );//DAMN COSTANT
```

That tells to IPB to NOT handle by itself the url that you are going to map (I think that this allow an external access)

So I ended up with the `.htaccess` from  @splash58 (thank you!)